# onSupportNavigateUp is called only on the start destination fragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have an activity with a navigation graph. In the toolbar, I have both the back button (on the left) and the close button (on the right). My setup looks like this

Activity Layout

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/appBarColor"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:navigationIcon="?homeAsUpIndicator"
        app:navigationIconTint="?attr/primaryTextColor"
        app:titleTextColor="?attr/primaryTextColor"
        tools:layout_height="50dp" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Activity OnCreate

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
navController = navHostFragment.navController
navController.graph = navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.activation_nav_graph)
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder().setFallbackOnNavigateUpListener { onSupportNavigateUp() }.build()
binding.toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

onCreateOptionsMenu to inflate the close button

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_buy_now, menu)
    return true
}
```

onOptionsItemSelected to handle the close button click

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == R.id.action_close) {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
        finish()
        return true
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

A custom onSupportNavigateUp to handle navigate up

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return when (currentDestination) {
        R.id.fragment1 -> {
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
            finish()
            return true
        }
        R.id.fragment3 -> {
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
            finish()
            return true
        }
        else -> navController.navigateUp()
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except the fact the onSupportNavigateUp in only called on the first fragment. i.e. The navigation graph has 4 fragments. If you press the back button from fragment 1, onSupportNavigateUp is called and is handled properly. But if you navigate to the 2nd, 3rd, or 4th fragment and press the back button in the toolbar, onSupportNavigateUp is not called. What could be reason?

Comment: if you override OnOptionsItemSelected, OnSupportNavigateUp will not be called. you can make sure it gets called by adding a default case.

Comment: This is not entirely true. As you can see I am already calling the default case. I fixed it. Check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the way I inflated the navigation graph didn't work. I changed Activity `OnCreated()`

```
binding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { onSupportNavigateUp() }
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
navController = navHostFragment.navController
navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
```

works properly now. Both onSupportNavigateUp and onOptionsItemSelected is called.